# How to disable this in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this to have no effect in a sub directory this .htaccess is in root i want to disable these features in subdirectory > /contact/ << = /public_html/contact/

```
# Use PHP54CGI as default
AddHandler fcgid54-script .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ live.php?content=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess in subdirectory with:

```
RewriteEngine off
```